# Generate Random Number Using Random Series

Tags: php, random, series

PHP Help

I have different series of code like this :

```
BT4YX***1
Eg:BT4DA1111
BT4YX**X1
Eg:BT4DA11A1
BT4Y**X*1
Eg:Bt4D22A21
```

I want to shuffle values of code with :

```
X=A,B,C,D,E
*=0 to 9
```

So, that in the end a random series will be picked up and shuffle values would be put in to that selected series that will finally give me code like this

```
BT4DA11A1
```

So far i did something like this :

```
$series = array("BT4YXXXX1", "BT4Y**X*1", "BT4Y**X*1", "BT4YX**X1", "BT4YX***1");
$random_series = $series[ rand(0,(count($series)-1)) ];
echo $random_series;
```

I'm able to get random series but stuck at putting random values of X and *

Please help me guys

Comment: I'd be inclined to use [preg_replace_callback()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) and have the callback assign the values

Answer (score 0):

```
$series = array(
        'BT4YX***1',
        'BT4YX**X1',
        'BT4Y**X*1',
        'BT4YXXXX1',
    );

$result = preg_replace_callback(
    '/[X*]/',
    function ($matches) {
        switch($matches[0]) {
            case '*' : return range(0,9)[array_rand(range(0,9))];
            case 'X' : return range('A','E')[array_rand(range('A','E'))];
        }
    },
    $series
);

var_dump($result);
```

**EDIT**

Requires PHP >= 5.4.0; but if you refactored the array dereferencing, you could use it with 5.3.0 or above, e.g.

```
$series = array(
        'BT4YX***1',
        'BT4YX**X1',
        'BT4Y**X*1',
        'BT4YXXXX1',
    );

$result = preg_replace_callback(
    '/[X*]/',
    function ($matches) {
        switch($matches[0]) {
            case '*' : 
                $range = range(0,9);
                $rand = array_rand($range);
                return $range[$rand];
            case 'X' :
                $range = range('A','E');
                $rand = array_rand($range);
                return $range[$rand];
        }
    },
    $series
);

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Thanks Mark however I'm getting Server error..and i recently bought hosting sever. I don't want to buy another one :( can't we do this with normal PHP version

Comment: Define `normal PHP version`: PHP 5.4.17 is a perfectly normal PHP version. I don't know what version you're running unless you say, so tell me

Comment: PHP Version = 5.3.26. Wow Excellent work Mark (y)... just one last thing -> I'm getting result like this "array(4) { [0]=> string(9) "BT4YE4091" [1]=> string(9) "BT4YB09B1" [2]=> string(9) "BT4Y97C71" [3]=> string(9) "BT4YDEDB1" }" how to echo a single random string ?

Comment: `echo $result[rand(0, count($result) - 1)];`